# Run Jenkins job when Pull request has been approved in GitHub?

Tags: git, jenkins

My project runs Jenkins job upon each Pull request. But I would like to run it after the Pull request has been approved at least by 2 people.

Currently I'm stuck at the web hook configurations.
Webhook works fine for opening new pull request job, but it fails when a new review is added. The web hook return back:

> **Error 400 Hook should contain event type**
>
> Hook should contain event type

I'm currently using below plugins for Jenkins:

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-api-plugin
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin

Comment: hi, did you get some solution for this. I even facing same issue, and need to trigger jenkin job when PR is approved.

Comment: @Chandra Hi, I ended up writing my own script in Jenkins. I used General Webhook Trigger plugin and in GitHub I created a new hook to trigger only when getting notified about pull request changes. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: @Soheil Does github notify PR approvals too? I looked at the list of events that would be notified on PR and it doesn't include approvals. Here is the list: "Pull request opened, closed, reopened, edited, assigned, unassigned, review requested, review request removed, labeled, unlabeled, synchronized, ready for review, converted to draft, locked, unlocked, auto merge enabled, auto merge disabled, milestoned, or demilestoned."